# non existence of weak derivative evans pde chapter 5 example 2

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Hi Im looking at the this very basic example, in proving the non existence of weak derivative.
[image]

I am confused in the last line
$$\cdots\lim_{m\to\infty}\left(\int_0^2 v\phi_m dx-\int_0^1\phi_m dx\right)=0$$.

Could anyone show me how this could be 0?  I tried but my answer was 1...

Thanks!

Comment: Just use Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem

Comment: i tried push the limit inside the integral sign but still do not get 1, could you demonstrate what you meant in perhaps 1 line of equation? Many thanks

Comment: You have that $v\phi_m \to 0$ pointwise (almost everywhere) and that $|v\phi_m| \leq |v| \in L^1$ So you can apply Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem. So $$\lim_{m\to +\infty} \int_0^2 v\phi_m = \int_0^2 \lim_{m\to +\infty}  v\phi_m = \int_0^2 0 dx = 0$$ Same thing with $\int_0^2 \lim_{m\to +\infty}  \phi_m$

Comment: thank you. But why $v\phi_m\to 0$ point wise? There is nowhere in the questions tell about the behaviour of $\phi_m$ as $m\to\infty$...

Comment: You should read more carefully, it's said in the definition of $\phi_m$ that $\phi_m(x) \to 0$ for $x\neq 1$

Comment: yes, but when we let $m\to\infty$, there should still be a point where $\phi_m(x)=1$, i mean at $x=1$, $\phi=1$...

Comment: What happens if you are integrating over a point?

Comment: 0....okay i remembered...thanks...